How can I access files on an OSX created encrypted .dmg file?
I have an encrypted .dmg file made on a Mac in OSX, I need to be able to access the files in it from my Ubuntu laptop.  I have read a few things about how to do this using things like dmg2iso but so far have had no luck.  However most of the things I have read about this are at least 10 years old so I am hoping things have gotten easier.
I used terminal to install dmg2iso and read a post about then using acetoneiso to mount the dmg, but when I run acetoneiso and use the menu item to mount a MacOS dmg I get an error saying "Unable to find poweriso in ~/.acetoneiso/. Please download it from: https://www.poweriso.com/poweriso-1.3.tar.gz and extract it to ~/.acetoneiso/ folder."
So I went to that link and downloaded the poweriso software but can't figure out how to find the ~/.acetoneiso folder to extract it into.
Any suggestions on either A) finding that folder to extract into and hoping it then works or, B) an easier way to access this encrypted .dmg file?
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

It is the first hidden folder in your personal folder. Activate the view of hidden files and folders in your file manager or use Midnight Commander

Thx, I activated the hidden folders option and found it, extracted the poweriso software into it, but now getting a new error.  "process error code 255", so now troubleshooting that...
